# Will there be QGIS for Playbook?

Tags: qgis

Does anyone know if a mobile version of QGIS is planned for the Blackberry Playbook. I know there is an android version, I tried converting it to .bar and gave up when it wouldn't load because it needed Minstro to configure. Any help here would be appreciated.

Comment: Try asking their mailing list as well

Answer (score 1):

There has been no talk about that so far, compare http://osgeo-org.1560.n6.nabble.com/Quantum-GIS-f4099105.html

Without a sponsor, I don't see that happening even if it would be technically possible (which I don't know).

Comment: Seems to me the number of professionals carrying around playbooks would outnumber android and ios. Not to mention the superior hardware.